# Integration of $\int (\frac{1-x}{1+x})^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: integration

I've been trying to integrate this for a long time but can't.

$$\int \left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

I tried assuming $\frac{1-x}{1+x}=t^3$ , also tried integration by parts but it gets stuck in a loop.

Comment: @David H ? (look below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** The obvious substitution here is $x=\frac{1-u}{1+u}$. Using this, we find:

$$\begin{align}
\int\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{\frac13}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int u^{\frac13}\cdot\frac{(-2)\,\mathrm{d}u}{(1+u)^2}\\
&=-2\int\frac{u^{\frac13}}{(1+u)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u.
\end{align}$$

Next, substitute $u=t^3$:

$$\begin{align}
-2\int\frac{u^{\frac13}}{(1+u)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u
&=-6\int\frac{t^3}{(1+t^3)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t.\\
\end{align}$$

This transforms the integrand to a rational function, so the rest of the problem is now just a matter of computation.

---

**EDIT:**

Since the integration of the rational function arrived at in the hint above isn't necessarily as straightforward as I initially thought, I'll go ahead and complete the solution.

First note that $$\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{2}{1+t^3}\right]=\frac{-6\,t^2}{(1+t^3)^2}.$$

Thus, integrating by parts we have:

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{-6\,t^3}{(1+t^3)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int t\left[\frac{-6\,t^2}{(1+t^3)^2}\right]\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{2\,t}{1+t^3}-2\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^3}.
\end{align}$$

The integral $\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^3}$ can be done by partial fractions.

$$\frac{1}{1+t^3}=\frac{1}{3(1+t)}+\frac{2-t}{3(1-t+t^2)}.$$

For convenience, we may rewrite the second term as:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2-t}{3(1-t+t^2)}
&=-\frac{-2+t}{3(1-t+t^2)}\\
&=-\frac{-4+2t}{6(1-t+t^2)}\\
&=-\frac{(-1+2t)-3}{6(1-t+t^2)}\\
&=-\frac{-1+2t}{6(1-t+t^2)}+\frac{3}{6(1-t+t^2)}\\
&=-\frac{-1+2t}{6(1-t+t^2)}+\frac{1}{2(1-t+t^2)}.
\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^3}
&=\frac13\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t}-\frac16\int\frac{-1+2t}{1-t+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t+\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-t+t^2}\\
&=\frac13\ln{(1+t)}-\frac16\ln{(1-t+t^2)}+\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-t+t^2}\\
&=\frac26\ln{(1+t)}-\frac16\ln{(1-t+t^2)}+\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-t+t^2}\\
&=\frac16\ln{\left[(1+t)^2\right]}-\frac16\ln{(1-t+t^2)}+\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-t+t^2}\\
&=\frac16\ln{\left[\frac{(1+t)^2}{1-t+t^2}\right]}+\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-t+t^2}\\
&=\frac16\ln{\left[\frac{(1+t)^3}{1+t^3}\right]}+\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-t+t^2}.
\end{align}$$

Finally, the integral $\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-t+t^2}$ can be found most easily by completing the square in the denominator. We have,

$$\begin{align}
t^2-t+1
&=\left(t^2-t+\frac14\right)+\left(1-\frac14\right)\\
&=\left(t-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34\\
&=\frac14\left(2t-1\right)^2+\frac34\\
&=\frac34\left(\frac{2t-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+\frac34\\
&=\frac34\left[\left(\frac{2t-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1\right].
\end{align}$$

Thus, a convenient substitution would be $\frac{2t-1}{\sqrt{3}}=r\implies t=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,r+1}{2}\implies \mathrm{d}t=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\,\mathrm{d}r$:

$$\begin{align}
\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-t+t^2}
&=\frac23\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\left(\frac{2t-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1}\\
&=\frac23\int\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\,\mathrm{d}r}{r^2+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{r^2+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan{\left(r\right)}+\color{grey}{constant}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan{\left(\frac{2t-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}+\color{grey}{constant}.
\end{align}$$

Hence,

$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^3}=\frac16\ln{\left[\frac{(1+t)^3}{1+t^3}\right]}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan{\left(\frac{2t-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}+\color{grey}{constant}.$$

Hence,

$$\int\frac{-6\,t^3}{(1+t^3)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{2\,t}{1+t^3}-\frac13\ln{\left[\frac{(1+t)^3}{1+t^3}\right]}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan{\left(\frac{2t-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}+\color{grey}{constant}.$$

Finally, to obtain the integral $\int\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{\frac13}\,\mathrm{d}x$, we simply substitute back $t=\sqrt[3]{u}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$ into the expression for the integral $\int\frac{-6\,t^3}{(1+t^3)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$ stated above. This comes out to,

$$\int\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{\frac13}\,\mathrm{d}x=(1-x)^{1/3}(1+x)^{2/3}-\frac13\ln{\left[\frac{(1+x)\left(1+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\right)^3}{2}\right]}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan{\left(\frac{2\sqrt[3]{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}+\color{grey}{constant}.$$

---

**Note:** As an aside, it's interesting to observe that by combining the anti-derivative I found with the anti-derivative Shadock gave in terms of hypergeometric functions, we can then deduce a closed-form for the Gauss hypergeometric function $_2F_1(\frac{2}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{5}{3}, \frac{x+1}{2})$.

Comment: In the last step should it be u^1/3 = t ?

Comment: ok i got that step!

Comment: In the first step shouldn't you substitute u = (1-x)/(1+x) not        x=(1-u)/(1+u)

Comment: Alright i got it, you assumed x=(1-u)/(1+u) so you could directly find du since u=(1-x)/(1+x) after substituting x=(1-u)/(1+u) , Right?

Comment: @user129048 You got it. ;) It also happens to be a substitution I use a lot and I know that function happens to be its own inverse, so naturally I sometimes don't bother to write down the inverse. And by the way, shoot me a comment if you think you need help solving the last integral.

Comment: haha yeah i'll need your help for that last integral –  
 give me a hint !

Comment: @user129048 Sorry for just now getting back to you. Unfortunately, you waited until I had already gone to sleep before asking for more help the other night, and I didn't have time for MSE the next day. As an apology, I've edited my response to include a detailed derivation of the rest of the problem. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :D! this problem turned out to be much more complicated than i had imagined.

Comment: @user129048 Indeed! I'm adding this problem to my list of potential exam problems because despite it's length and difficulty it's nevertheless doable using only high school calculus technique. Out of curiosity, did you encounter this integral somewhere, or did you think it up just for fun?

Comment: @DavidH I think sometimes Wolfram Alpha will return an antiderivative that seems strange because it is valid over a larger domain on the complex plane. That might be the case here. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @RandomVariable Yes, I've noticed that on occasion. However, I don't believe that's what is going on in this case. You can check that WRA *can* return an elementary anti-derivative for $\int\frac{u^{\frac13}}{(1+u)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u$ like what I derived in my response above, and the only difference between that integral and the one in the OP is the substitution $u=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$. I think the reason only reason WRA doesn't return an elementary anti-derivative for that integral is that it exceeds the number of allowable characters.

Comment: @DavidH This problem was being discussed in class when i walked in halfway through, though the prof erased it before i had a chance to make sense of the solution

Comment: @user129048 Well, in that case do you remember enough of what your professor did to tell if my solution is similar to what he did?

Comment: Yes i think its pretty similar to what he did,

Answer (score 1):

The answer of wolfram alpha is

$
\int (\frac{1-x}{1+x})^{1/3} dx = \frac{(2^{1/3}*(1-x)^{2/3}*_2F_1(\frac{2}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{5}{3}, \frac{x+1}{2})-2 x+2)}{2*(\frac{1-x}{1+x})^{2/3}}+constant
$

with F the hypergeometric function...
So good luck for you  ^^

Yann

Comment: I suspect that the reason Wolfram Alpha returned an answer in terms of a hypergeometric function is that the anti-derivative I found in my response would require too many characters to display.

Comment: I'm a chemist so I can't help ... ^^

Answer (score -1):

Hint:
$(\frac{(1-x)}{(1+x)^{1/3}}=(\frac 1{(1+x))^{1/3}}-(\frac{(x)}{(1+x))^{1/3}}   $[can you break $(\frac{(x)}{(1+x))^{1/3}}   $ more to get a suitable form?]

After edit Hint:

Try with trigonometric function.

Comment: Sorry for the question in the unedited form I take it what is given in the previous form....

Comment: I fail to see how your suggestion to try using trigonometric functions is a helpful hint. Can you elaborate?